# PHP, Ajax , insert data to function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have this PHP function:

```
function _test($pram)
{
    return echo 'aaaf';
}
```

How can I insert AJAX data into that PHP function, as far as i can search on google, AJAX will load only on single PHP pages.

My JavaScript code:

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $.ajax({url: "function.php", success: function(result){
        //
    }});
});
```

`function.php` contains multiple functions with parameters

Comment: Can you show us the JavaScript code where you call your PHP file with Ajax?

Comment: $("button").click(function(){
    $.ajax({url: "funtion.php", success: function(result){
        alert('testd');
    }});
});


inside the function.php are series of php functions

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code, you either can add GET parameters to the URL you are requesting, or make it a POST request with POST data.

A GET request:

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url     : "function.php?key=value",
        success : function(result) { }
    });
});
```

And in PHP:

```
function _test($pram)
{
    return echo isset($_GET['key']) ? $_GET['key'] : '';
}
```

---

A POST request:

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        data    : { key: "value" },
        method  : "POST",
        url     : "function.php",
        success : function(result) { }
    });
});
```

And in PHP:

```
function _test($pram)
{
    return echo isset($_POST['key']) ? $_POST['key'] : '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP is server-side, Ajax is client side.

You should create a file containing that function. That way, Apache will create a link to that file using the path URL. For example:

You create that file called `function.php`

You insert your PHP function:

```
function _test($pram)
{
    return echo 'aaaf';
}
```

You call that file with Ajax, from your HTML page on the **client side**:

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "function.php",
  data: { name: "John" }
})
  .done(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
  });
```

The only thing you need to do, is tell PHP to call that function with the proper parameter. They explain how you can read JSON data from PHP in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18866571/receive-json-post-with-php).

It comes down to this for you basically:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
_test($data["name"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If that is what you want:

```
function _test($pram)
{
    return echo 'aaaf';
}

if(isset($_POST['parameter'])) return _test($_POST['parameter']);
```

---

```
$.post({
    url:'function.php',
    data:{parameter:"test"},
    success:function(data)
    {
        console.log("Server returned:",data);
    }
});
```

Send `POST` request to the php file and then read it with `$_POST['variable'];`